# spring security StateKeyGenerator custom instance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to have better control of the "state" param used in OAuth2 with spring security.

[DefaultStateKeyGenerator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/filter/state) just returns a random 6 character string.

`AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider` has a `setStateKeyGenerator` but I'm not sure how to get an instance to call the setter.

I find it strange that `StateKeyGenerator` takes an `OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails`, but the default implementation just ignores it and there's no details on how to configure your own

```
~/repos/jtor > mvn dependency:tree | grep security
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:test
```

Comment: really....nobody has any thoughts??? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage, you can implement your own `StateKeyGenerator`  then configure beans to use it. You're free to use the `resource` if it's relevant to your use case but it's ok to ignore it!

Here is a possible configuration:

```java
@Bean
public StateKeyGenerator stateKeyGenerator() {
    return new CustomStateKeyGenerator();
}

@Bean
public AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider() {
    AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
    accessTokenProvider.setStateKeyGenerator(stateKeyGenerator());
    return accessTokenProvider;
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(myResource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest));
    restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider());
    return restTemplate;
}
```